# Excel vba check if number is null: doesn't work as expected

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this sample program I've written to understand a similar issue in a bigger program. I have a `a As Variant` and `b As Double`. `a` gets equal to `Null`, while `b` gets equal to zero. Then I proceed to check if `a` or `b` is `Null`.

```
Sub testNull()
    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As Double

    a = Null
    b = 0

    If a = Null Then
        MsgBox (a & "null") 'doesn't print
    ElseIf a <> Null Then
        MsgBox (a & " not null") 'doesn't print
    Else
        MsgBox (b & " don't know") 'prints
    End If

    If b = Null Then
        MsgBox (b & "null") 'doesn't print
    ElseIf b <> Null Then
        MsgBox (b & " not null") 'doesn't print
    Else
        MsgBox (b & " don't know") 'prints
    End If

End Sub
```

The results show that while excel doesn't consider `a` or `b` to be `Null`, at the same time it doesn't consider any of those to *not* be `Null`.

What is the correct way to make the check here? What causes the issues?

Comment: Use the `IsNull` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing anything against `Null` (including the equality test `Null = Null`) returns `Null`, not `True` or `False`.

To check for a `Null`, use the `IsNull` function, e.g.

```
If IsNull(a) Then
    MsgBox "a is null"
Else
    '...
```

Comment: Just as an elaboration on this: VBA cannot compare the unknown to anything (even when comparing it to the unknown itself). So, comparing the unkown (NULL) to something is simply not possible with an `=`. Hence, there is a special function for that. Maybe also noteworthy on this subject: put into cell `A1` the formula `=1/0` and copy it over to cell `B1` and then check if `=A1=B1`. Once again you don't get the "expected" result because the cell yields an error and errors cannot be compared with an `=`. Once again a special function is required `=IsError()`.

Comment: @Ralph In VBA, you can also check an error using `=`.  For instance, if A1 had the formula `=1/0`, then VBA would return `True` for `Range("A1").Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)`.  The `IsError` function will check against **all** error types, but specific ones need to be tested by comparing to the specific code.

Comment: Thank you! I knew of the function `IsNull` but didn't think a simple `=` or `<>` wouldn't work as well. Caused a lot of pain.